# exercise 9.7 Kochan. strange output

Tags: c

I am working to learn C using Kochan's Programming in C 4th edition.  problem 9.7 the goal is to insert a string of characters into another array.  I am supposed to write a function to accomplish this.  I have two problems.

When I have the algorithm print the result as it goes through the if statements, it produces the desired output, however when I change it to an %s, I only get a partial output.  My hunch is that a null character is being placed where i do not want it, but I simply cannot see it.

To see what was happening, I added a printf that would track the letter and the array space it was occupying.  I was surprised to see that the first letter was not 0, but was blank, and the next letter was assigned the 0.  Any insight into this would be appreciated.

The funtion of interest is "insertString".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char x[] = {"the wrong son was shot that day"};
char text[] = {"per"};

int countString (char x[])
{
    int counter, z;

    for (counter = 0; x[counter] != '\0'; ++counter)
    z = counter+1;

    return z;
}

void insertString (char text[],char x[],int n) //source, text to input, where
{

    int count, clock, i = countString(text), q = countString(x);
    int counter = 0;

    char y[i + q];

   for(count = 0; x[count] != '\0'; ++count){
        if (count < n){
            y[count] = x[count];
            printf("%c  %i", y[count], count);   //The integer call is just to put a number next to the 
                                                  //letter.  This is where my second issue is shown.
            }
        else if (counter <= i){
            y[count] = text[counter];
            ++counter;
            printf("%c", y[count]);
        }
        else{
            y[count]= x[count - counter];
            printf("%c", y[count]);
        }
   }
   printf("\n\n");
   y[count-counter] = '\0';

 printf("%s", y);

}


int main (void)
{
            void insertString(char text[], char x[], int i);
            int countString(char x[]);
            int i;

            insertString(text, x, 10);

            return 0;
}
```

10 out of 10 times I post here it is because im doing something dumb, so I use SO as an absolute last resort if i am getting into the territory of just randomly trying stuff with no methodology.  Thanks for your patience in advance.

Comment: That seems like an overly complicated `insertString` function if all it's doing is inserting a bit of text into another string at a particular point. Is it supposed to do things like `insertString("example", "moo", 4)` and give you `"examoople"`?

Comment: Tip: In C try and use pointers to do the heavy lifting for you instead of using intermediate counters. Use the pointer *as* a counter. `for (char* p = x; *p; ++p)` is a simple way of walking through a NULL-terminated string. If you need bounds checking you can make your loop condition more like `*p && (p - x < len)` or something like that, or have a "max pointer value" computed in advance, like `char* l = x + len`.

Comment: yes, that is what it is supposed to do.  Pointers is the next chapter, and are not used for these exercises

Comment: You should make a secondary function to move a portion of the string further down to make room for the insertion, then perform the insertion. If you can use `strcpy` you're already done. **Be sure that the target buffer has sufficient memory allocated to make the move**. Here `text` is *way* too short.

Comment: Another tip: Do not declare functions inside of functions. Those two definitions inside of `main()` are not supposed to be there. As the functions are defined above they're redundant and can be eliminated.

Comment: Any C introduction should start with pointers since that's how anyone gets anything done and not understanding that out of the gate is asking for trouble. Can you just skip ahead to the part where they teach you C instead of whatever's going on here?

Comment: In `countString`, your `for` loop should have a `;` at the end of the line. It _may_ still work, but I supect you really want `z` to be set _after_ the loop ends and _not_ while the loop is executing. That is, you _don't_ want `z = ...` to be part of the loop body. As it is, if the string is _empty_, `z` will _never_ be set. This is undefined behavior. This would be flagged as "may be uninitialized" by the compiler if you compiled with `-Wall`

Comment: The y[] is set to 34, large enough to contain the original array and the insert string.

Comment: I think the exercise is a bit different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your condition is wrong in the `for`. It should be `x[count - counter] != '\0'`
2. In the second condition use just `<` to avoid overindexing. (`else if (counter < i)`)
3. You put the terminating NULL char at wrong place. You should do this: `y[count] = '\0'`

Comment: @JerrySingh Strange it prints for me. https://onlinegdb.com/SyXAfbNBL

Comment: so working.  Id gone around and around with the count - counter etc etc.  Thanks.  Any idea with why the "t" wouldnt be assigned y[0]?  I assue it is also some little stupidity in the algorithm

Comment: @JerrySingh Can you give the exact inputs? Or when this problem occur?

Comment: In the first "for" loop in the insertString function.  When I printf("%c %i", y[count], count); the output is  "t h0 e1 etc."  shouldnt the 't' be '0'?                                                                                                   Its in the code put in above, where the note is.

Comment: @JerrySingh No it should not. What makes you think that? If count is 0 then y[count] is `t` at the point when you print it since you assigned x[count] to it in the above line. And x[count] is x[0] which is `t`.

Comment: ok i got it, im a dope.  was reading the output wrong because of spacing.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` inside a string routine like this is fine for debugging, but it's a poor way to write a general-purpose function because it makes it impossible to use its output for further programmatic manipulation. It can also make it difficult to reason about how the state of the function interacts in unpredictable ways with the state of the printed data.

I assume you haven't learned about [dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) which is a prerequisite to returning strings from functions. You can inline the function logic into main or `printf` only at the end of the function in the meantime.

Adding to this point, a `void` function would need to reallocate space in the string to insert into and would be [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm). This seems likely less generally useful than allocating a new string to hold the result.

Using global variables like `char x[]` when there's no need is poor practice. It's better to put those strings scoped to `main`. Since your function can access these variables in addition to its parameters, confusion can ensue when scope and encapsulation is breached.

Use consistent formatting and avoid variable names like `q` that mean virtually nothing. Instead of adding comments to explain poor var names:

```
void insertString (char text[],char x[],int n) //source, text to input, where
```

You can simply name the variables exactly what they represent:

```
void insertString(char *dest, char *source, int add_index)
```

Also, now that you've mastered `countString`, you can abstract this by calling the builtin `strlen`.

Be sure to allocate enough space in buffers: `char y[i + q];` should be `y[i+q+1]` to allow room for the null terminator `'\0'`.

As for the logic, I think it's easier to break into three loops without conditions instead of one loop with conditions. This makes it easier to break the problem down into the three constituent steps:

1. Add everything up until `add_index` from the `dest` string to the result.
2. Add everything in the `source` string to the result.
3. Add everything after `add_index` from the `dest` string to the result.

Using this approach, all that's left is figuring out how to map the indexes appropriately. Here it is in code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *insert_string(char *dest, char *source, int add_index) {
    int source_len = strlen(source);
    int dest_len = strlen(dest);
    int result_size = source_len + dest_len + 1;
    char *result = malloc(result_size);

    for (int i = 0; i < add_index; i++) {
        result[i] = dest[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < source_len; i++) {
        result[i+add_index] = source[i];
    }

    for (int i = add_index; i < dest_len; i++) {
        result[i+add_index] = dest[i];
    }

    result[result_size-1] = '\0';
    return result;
}    

int main(void) {
    char *result = insert_string("hello world", "cruel ", 6);
    printf("%s\n", result);
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Although this is likely for instructional purposes, these operations can be abstracted further using builtin string functions like [`strncpy`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) and [`sprintf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *insert_string(char *dest, char *source, int add_index) {
    int result_size = strlen(dest) + strlen(source) + 1;
    char *result = malloc(result_size);
    char pre[add_index+1];
    pre[add_index] = '\0';
    strncpy(pre, dest, add_index);
    sprintf(result, "%s%s%s", pre, source, dest + add_index); 
    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    char *result = insert_string("hello world", "cruel ", 6);
    printf("%s\n", result);
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Doing this in-place is more straightforward. Since the result already has the prefix, you can copy the destination postfix to create a source-sized gap in the middle and then overwrite the gap using the source string. It's up to the caller to make sure that the destination buffer is large enough to hold the insertion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void insert_string(char *dest, char *source, int add_index) {
    int source_len = strlen(source);
    int dest_len = strlen(dest);

    for (int i = add_index; i < dest_len; i++) {
        dest[i+add_index] = dest[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < source_len; i++) {
        dest[i+add_index] = source[i];
    }
}

int main(void) {
    // allocate extra space in the string to hold the insertion
    char greeting[32] = "hello world";
    insert_string(greeting, "cruel ", 6);
    printf("%s\n", greeting);
    return 0;
}
```

A note of caution: none of these functions handle errors at all, so they're unsafe. Correct functions should check that the `add_index` falls within the bounds of the `dest` string. This is an exercise for the reader.

Comment: the exercise is a bit different.

Comment: for sure sprintf  is not something the author of the book wanted to see. They suppose to learn pointers and arrays

Comment: That's why I provided two examples, one with the functions and one without. I think it's instructive to show both. It's trivial to re-write these for in-place versions if desired. I can add them.

Comment: You are correct, ive not gotten to memory allocation.  pointers is next.

Answer (score 0):

The original exercise is here:

[image]

Your function is not doing it. You need to insert the string into another string **not** to create a new one with both mixed. You can do it this way of course and then copy it into the original one - but it is the most uneficient way to archive it (memory & timewise).

Use the correct types.

```
size_t mystrlen(const char *str)
{
    const char *end = str;
    while(*end++);

    return end - str - 1;
}

char *strinsert(char *dest, size_t pos, const char *istr)
{
    char *temp = dest, *work;
    size_t ilen = mystrlen(istr);
    size_t nmove;

    while(*temp) temp++;
    nmove = temp - dest - pos + 1;
    work = temp;
    temp += ilen;

    while(nmove--) *temp-- = *work--;
    work = dest + pos;
    while(*istr) *work++ = *istr++;

    return dest;
} 


int main()
{
    char dest[128] = "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789";

    printf("%s", strinsert(dest, 7, "ABCD"));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/KMnLU2

Comment: hrmm you might be right regarding the exercise.  I do not have pointers at my disposal though.